# variable undefined after findOne operation mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to make an API that makes use of 2 databases to generate a fine. Here is the code:

```
router.get("/generateFine/:bookingID/:currDate", function (req, res, next) {
    var currDate,
        returnDate,
        fine,
        totalFine = 0;
    Booking.findOne({ _id: req.params.bookingID }).then(function (booking) {
        Car.findOne({ _id: booking.carID }).then(function (car) {
            currDate = Date.parse(req.params.currDate) / 1000 / 3600 / 24;
            returnDate = Date.parse(booking.bookingDates[1]) / 1000 / 3600 / 24;
            fine = car.fine;
            if (currDate > returnDate) {
                totalFine = fine * (currDate - returnDate);
            }
            console.log(totalFine);
            // res.send(totalFine);
        });
        console.log("totalFine is " + totalFine);
        // res.send(totalFine);
    });
});
```

Here are the two Schemas used in the code:
Booking Schema:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("621bf46602edf12942f0d5c9"),
    "carID" : "621b87af70c150da70b1dabf",
    "bookingDates" : [ 
        "2022-03-05", 
        "2022-03-06"
    ],
}
```

Car Schema:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("621b87af70c150da70b1dabf"),
    "name" : "Toyota",
    "rate" : 60,
    "fine" : 10,
    "datesBooked" : [ 
        {
            "from" : "2022-03-05",
            "to" : "2022-03-06"
        }, 
        {
            "from" : "2022-03-07",
            "to" : "2022-03-08"
        }, 
        {
            "from" : "2022-03-09",
            "to" : "2022-03-10"
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I want to return the generated fine to the user. When I am trying to send the result, it throwing an error. The first console log prints the correct result, but the second console log prints 0. Also, how can I send the result without getting an error.
Thanks already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation pipeline stage to include the car document that matches on the `carID` field, create additional computed fields that will aid you in getting the total fine whilst using the necessary aggregation operators.

Essentially you would need to run an aggregate pipeline that follows:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

router.get('/generateFine/:bookingID/:currDate', async function (req, res, next) {
    const currDate = new Date(req.params.currDate);
    const [{ totalFine }] = await Booking.aggregate([
        { $match: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.bookingID) }},
        { $lookup: {
            from: 'cars', // or from: Car.collection.name
            let: { carId: { $toObjectId: '$carID' } }, // convert the carID string field to ObjectId for the match to work correctly
            pipeline: [ 
                { $match: {
                    $expr: { $eq: [ '$_id', '$$carId' ] }
                } }
            ],
            as: 'car'
        } },
        { $addFields: { 
            car: { $arrayElemAt: ['$car', 0 ] }, // get the car document from the array returned above
            returnDate: {
                $toDate: { $arrayElemAt: ['$bookingDates', 1 ]}
            }
        } },
        // compute the overdue days 
        { $addFields: { 
            overdueDays: {
                $trunc: {
                    $ceil: {
                        $abs: {
                            $sum: { 
                                $divide: [
                                    { $subtract: [currDate, '$returnDate'] },
                                    60 * 1000 * 60 * 24
                                ] 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } },
        { $project: { // project a new field
            totalFine: { 
                $cond: [
                    { $gt: [currDate, '$returnDate'] }, // IF current date is greater than return date
                    { $multiply: ['$car.fine',  '$overdueDays'] }, // THEN multiply car fine with the overdue days
                    0 // ELSE total fine is 0
                ]
            }
        } }
    ]).exec();

    console.log("totalFine is " + totalFine);
    // res.send(totalFine);
});
```

Comment: Hey! thank you so much for this! Also, what is the best resource you would suggest to learn mongodb and other related stuff? I'm a fresher wanting to be a humble tech lead like you :)

Comment: @AmijeetThakur Thank you and I'm quite humbled by your aspirations. My recommendation is to use the official MongoDB university as first beginners starting point, then follow the mongodb tag on this platform, try to solve some of the questions and provide the answers to gain confidence and level up